# Никак не отправляется запрос

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

Пересмотрел кучу видео, статей, делал всё как там, запрос не отправляется, никакой реакции от скрипта. jQuery подключён, работает.

Сам запрос:

```
$(':button').click(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')    
        }
    });  

    var commentText = $('#comment_input').val();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'/comment',
        data: {comment: commentText},           
        success: function(data){ $('#info').html(data); }
    }); 
});
```

Роут:

```
Route::post('/comment', ['as'=>'comment', 'uses' => 'CommentController@addComment' ] );
```

И контроллер.

```
public function addComment(Request $request){
    $comment =  $request->input('comment');
    return response()->json($comment);
}
```

разметка

С Ajax'ом работал много, писал и на чистом JS, на jQuery, в приложениях на чистом PHP. Но с Laravel что-то пошло не так. Просмотрел инструкции, вроде всё просто, прописать url, принять запрос, получить ответ. Но не работает.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86236/discussion-on-question-by-sebastian-melmot----).

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в уровнях запроса, при пути `url:'/comment'`, запрос отправлялся на `http://mtochie/comment`, в то время, как контроллер располагался на `http://mtochie/public/comment`. Для отправки запроса надо дописать путь до `url:'/comment',`, или вставить функцию с именем пути `url:'{{ route('comment') }}',` Важно добавить в запрос заголовок с токеном, без него сервер не даст доступ, выдав ошибку 500.